# Timetable schedule and students allocation

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, or-tools, mixed-integer-programming, clp

I want to optimize an allocation of courses to students respecting their wishes.
Every student grades all courses with numbers (eg. 1-6, more is better)
20 courses are assigned to 5 timeslots, so in each timeslot 3-6 courses are synchronous. I am looking for an optimal timetable of the courses and the students' allocation to courses, so that the global sum of grades is maximum.

My problem is the conflict, that a student cannot be in 2 courses in the same timeslot. In an LP formula I have the product of two boolean Variable

```
sum( student[coursenr] * timeslot[coursenr] ) <= 1
```

That's obviously not linear and has to solved with slack Variables, with many slack Variables. And even more new Constraints. Only very small problems are solvable.
How can I improve my model?

Comment: Use CP-SAT, use only Boolean variable, like assign[student][coursenr][timeslot].

Comment: Good Idea, but then I have (too) many And Clauses:
for all i:
  AND (student[coursenr], timeslot[coursenr],student[coursenr+i], timeslot[coursenr+i]) = 0

Comment: Here's a similar example: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/contrib/school_scheduling_sat.py#L83